# How do I properly bind a WPF TreeView control and effectively display a hierarchy of the data?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

Ok, so I normally wait until the last possible moment to submit a question but I could really use some help.

I'm attempting to bind an `ObservableCollection<Contact_Info>` to a WPF `TreeView` Control. Contact_Info contains properties for contact information and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It also contains a list of more detailed information for the given `Contact`.

I'm having trouble with 2 things. 1) I need to display on the `TreeViewItem` header the name of the Company however, a lot of the Contacts have a missing Company Name in which, I want to use the First and Last name. I have attempted to use things like `FallBackValue` and `TargetNullValue` but the CompanyName is not null, its just empty so I can't seem to get that right. Do I need a converter? 2) I cannot seem to get the hierarchy correct in that, I want all Contacts of the same AccountID to be grouped together within a `TreeViewItem`. Currently, I can only get the Company Name to display on the `TreeViewItem` and expanding it displays a blank value and there are still duplicate Company Names displayed..

Code for my attempt at a HierarchicalDataTemplate placed under the DockPanel.Resources (not sure if that's the right place either).

```
    <local:Main_Interface x:Key="MyList" />
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type 
                                 local:Contact_Info}" ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=OppDataList}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CompanyName}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
       <DataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type sharpspring:SharpspringOpportunityDataModel}" >
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProjectName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

The above code is the most recent thing I have tried among countless other ways. I feel that I'm really close but at this point I could really use some help from SO..

The other classes are a little long so let me know if you need more. Any help provided is greatly appreciated!

Edit 1: Contact_Info

```
public class Contact_Info : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    internal SharpspringLeadDataModel LeadDataModel;
    internal SharpspringOpportunityDataModel OppData;
    public List<SharpspringOpportunityDataModel> OppDataList { get; set; }// Should i make this ObservableCollection?

    public Project_Info ProjectInfo { get; set; }
    public bool IsDirty { get; set; }
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }

    #region Properties

    public long AccountID
    {
        get => LeadDataModel.AccountID;
        set
        {
            if (value != LeadDataModel.AccountID)
            {
                LeadDataModel.AccountID = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public long LeadID
    {
        get => LeadDataModel.LeadID;
        set
        {
            if (value != LeadDataModel.LeadID)
            {
                LeadDataModel.LeadID = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    // Lead Info
    public string CompanyName
    {
        get => LeadDataModel.CompanyName;
        set
        {
            if (value != LeadDataModel.CompanyName)
            {
                LeadDataModel.FaxNumber = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public Contact_Info(SharpspringLeadDataModel lead, SharpspringOpportunityDataModel opp)
    {
        LeadDataModel = lead;
        OppData = opp;
        ProjectInfo = new Project_Info(this);

    }

    public SharpspringLeadDataModel GetDataModel()
    {
        return LeadDataModel;
    }

    public SharpspringOpportunityDataModel GetOppModel()
    {
        return OppData;
    }

    public Project_Info GetProjectInfoModel()
    {
        return ProjectInfo;
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        IsDirty = true;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Currently populates tree but does not group Companies together...

```
private void PopulateTreeView(List<SharpspringLeadDataModel> lead_list, List<SharpspringOpportunityDataModel> opp_list)
    {
        Contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact_Info>();
        var complete2 =
                        from lead in lead_list
                        let oppList = from o in opp_list
                                      where o.PrimaryLeadID == lead.LeadID
                                      select o
                        select new Contact_Info()
                        {
                            LeadDataModel = lead,
                            OppData = oppList.DefaultIfEmpty(new SharpspringOpportunityDataModel()).First(),
                            OppDataList = oppList.ToList(),
                        };

        Contacts = complete2.ToObservableCollection();
   Lead_Treeview.ItemsSource = Contacts;
}
```

Comment: whats OppDataList? is it Contact_Info? Please how the class definition of Contact_Info

Comment: OppDataList is a list of Opportunities for the Contact in question. This is for a CRM so an Opportunity is simply just more information that's related to the Contact. I would like the list of these Opportunities name to be shown when expanding a TreeViewItem. So essentially I'd have a TreeViewItem which would be the company name and expanded would show each Contact for that company. The list of opps would then be available after clicking the Contacts name.

Comment: i failed to see any hierarchy structure. I think its just a list

Comment: Perhaps that's what I'm missing? What do you mean by hierarchy structure? In the XML or C#? If i can figure out how to create a solid template i think that would solve my issues. The problem is, there seems to be 100 different ways to create the template and am not sure which is best.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Any suggestions on how to consolidate some of it? I was thinking that I could potentially bind only the necessary properties that would allow me to 'lookup' the rest of the needed data but I'm at a loss... I have added an edit to show the how the tree is being populated now. See anything out of place? Do I need to use TreeView.DataContext instead of ItemsSource? I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is really with using `List` instead of `ObservableCollection` for `OppDataList`. Using your code (reduced to minimal needed) but with the `ObservableCollection` driving the collection it works fine for me.

*Note that my code will work fine with List even because its all static but in a proper app you'll need OC to track changes in collection.*

*Disclaimer: I'm using code behind to answer this question to keep it simple but I do not recommend any such use in any real app*

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="240" Width="320">
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Contact_Info}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OppDataList}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SharpspringOpportunityDataModel}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProjectName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CompanyName}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using WpfApp1.Annotations;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Contact_Info> Contacts { get; } =
            new ObservableCollection<Contact_Info>
            {
                new Contact_Info
                {
                    CompanyName = "Apple",
                    OppDataList = {new SharpspringOpportunityDataModel {ProjectName = "World take over"}}
                },
                new Contact_Info
                {
                    CompanyName = "Google",
                    OppDataList = {new SharpspringOpportunityDataModel {ProjectName = "World take over"}}
                },
                new Contact_Info
                {
                    CompanyName = "Microsoft",
                    OppDataList = {new SharpspringOpportunityDataModel {ProjectName = "World take over"}}
                }
            };


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class Contact_Info
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<SharpspringOpportunityDataModel> OppDataList { get; } =
            new ObservableCollection<SharpspringOpportunityDataModel>();
    }

    public class SharpspringOpportunityDataModel
    {
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for this. I will give it a shot. Just so i understand correctly, your disclaimer is about how you set the example up for demonstration purposes? In other words, the rest of the code is ok or is there something else you would not recommend? Also, using this example, do i need to set the DataContext of the TreeView or ItemsSource, or is this handled by the binding? Thanks again!

Comment: Sweet! I think I can make this work! I still have duplicate companies displayed but i think that's because of my underlying collection that ill work on but it is displaying the relationship properly. You're awesome! Thanks! p.s. - How did you change the color of the title bar on the window to red??

Comment: Disclaimer implies I expect you and future visitors to be doing this via proper MVVM implementation and not take the shortcut I took for the purpose of this example.

As for Red title bar: my windows 10 theme's primary color is set to Rust + Color title bar option set.

Comment: Also if you have any doubts about mvvm implementation or want general guidance with wpf that may not be a good SO question, you can drop in our [WPF Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf) to discuss it further with very knowledgeable residents (usually active in EU mornings - US afternoons Mon-Fri)

Comment: Thanks @Maverick I appreciate that. I feel that my implementation is really similar to MVVM and I've done some reading up on it recently. Ill definitely keep that in mind. Thanks again for all the help! -- ha i tried to join the chat room and i dont have enough rep to talk... Hopefully my rep will go up soon. Thanks again

Comment: @Maverick - I know you already helped me with this but i was wondering if you would be available in chat sometime to answer a few questions? Let me know if you can. I really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

based on my understanding your OppDataList is the sub property for the given Contract info and you want it to be collapsible.

In such case you can do

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourContactList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Header="{Binding ProjectName}">
                    <Expander Header="{Binding CompanyName}">
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding OppDataList}">
                            <!--Your OppDataList display-->
                        </ListBox>
                    </Expander>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

End result will look similar to this

```
+Contract1
-Contract2
   -Project2
      -Company2
         -Opp
            1
            2
            3
+Contract3
```

Comment: I like this because it gave me a different way to group my lists however, I'm running into issues still. How do i specify another DataTemplate? In other words i have the correct hierarchy but not enough levels. I keep getting 'ItemTemplate is set more than once' when attempting to add another child node.

Comment: @ZacHerman just add another node to your YourContactList and you will have another child. for another level you can just add another expander